# material-ui backdrop -- fails with invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to use material ui backdrop element in my code.  I am referring to this example: https://mui.com/components/backdrop/#example

As soon as I introduce this code into my component, it fails with error message as below.

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

My code is as below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Box,Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import CategoryCard from '../shop-categories/category-card'
import { useSelector  } from 'react-redux';
//import NavigateBeforeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NavigateBefore';
//import ProductsInCategory from '../../../pages/shops/product-in-category';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop'
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    heading : {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        fontWeight: 700,
        lineHeight: 1,
        color: props => props.pColor
    }
})


export default function CategoryGrid(props) {
  const { categories, shopId, title} = props;

  const shopColors = useSelector(state => state.main.currentShop)
  const classes = useStyles(shopColors);
  const router = useRouter()
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };


  const  gotoSubCategories = (shopId, id,cat_Name) => {
    setOpen(true)
    router.push(`/shops/shop-sub-categories?shop=${shopId}&category=${id}&categoryName=${cat_Name}`)
  }

    return (
      <>
        <div>
        <Backdrop sx={{color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer +1}}
                  open={open}
                  onClick={handleClose}
        >
          <CircularProgress color='inherit' />
        </Backdrop>
        </div>
          <Typography variant="body2" style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                className={classes.heading}>
              {title}
          </Typography>
          <Box display="flex" mb={2} mx={1} flexDirection="column">
            <Box display="flex" fontWeight='fontWeightBold' width={1/2} mb={1}>
          </Box>
          <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap">
          {
            categories.map((category, index) => {
              return <CategoryCard key={index}
                                name={category.name}
                                onClick={() => gotoSubCategories(shopId, category.id,category.name)}
                                imageURL={category.url}
                                shopId={shopId} callParent={props.callParent}
                     />
                })
          }
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </>
    )
  }
```

If I remove out this portion, then it works fine.

```
<div>
   <Backdrop sx={{color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer +1}}
           open={open}
           onClick={handleClose}
   >
   <CircularProgress color='inherit' />
   </Backdrop>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: props do not exist outside of the CategoryGrid function, so you can't do "color: props => props.pColor" in makeStyles

Comment: ok, why does it fail, only when I introduce Backdrop..

Comment: Does the error disappear if you remove the `sx` prop of `Backdrop`?

Comment: No.  It doesn't go away.

Comment: Recently the React version got updated from 16 to 17.x.  Not sure if this could be a problem?

Comment: Yeah it's [possible](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#mismatching-versions-of-react-and-react-dom). I see there is nothing wrong with your hook usage. If `Backdrop` throws because of invalid hook inside, then shouldn't `CategoryGrid` throws first because it also uses hooks?